# 3D Dynamics - avoding gimbal lock (a possible new method)

Tags: webgl

This question may violate the rules where one should not ask long winded questions.  But then my response is the following: can someone point me to a place where I can ask this question…  (or frame the question properly)?

First, to put this in context, I am a professor of mechanical engineering with a specialty in dynamics.  So I know the problem of gimbal lock and I understand quarternions, euler angles and, when necessary, tait-bryan angles.

I have developed a new approach to 3D Dynamics.  This method, based on Lie Algebra, Moving Frames and a new notation; and it makes 3D Dynamics easy.  It has the potential to resolve singularities but without the complexity of quarternions.

My hope is to demonstrate that this method can resolve such issues in computer graphics.

Now I have coded in OpenGL, SGI Inventor and now in webGL.  I have used proEngineer and Blender.  So I will be able to follow a discussion relating to those should you wish to explain that way.

Now here is the question….

How is gimbal lock resolved in webGL?  And even then: what does one mean by “resolve”?  For all of this is not clear to me.

Yes, I can avoid certain motions that bring the inner frame toward a singularity.  That would solve it.  Or when I approach the singularity, I can switch to quarternions.  Or I can add another motion degree. These are all different “classifications” of solutions: some at the user level, some at the coder level.

So, let’s say I have a method (not in the C++ sense of the word – but then, who knows, right)… a method that allows a user to implement a 3D rotation an easier way.

Does it come down to my asking the developers of webGL to implement a new method?
webGL_quarternion
webGL_euler_angle
webGL_new_method_in_moving frame

Will the new method be coded on the old ones?  For example, do quarternion calls, in turn, call to euler angle methods?

I am just trying to find a way to demonstrate that this new method will be much more useful to computer graphics programmers or users (e.g.: Blender users).

Answer (score 0):

WebGL does not use any specific method whatsoever to manage rotations; if it appears to you that it does, then you must have been using some high-level library to do it for you that is hiding the foundation of WebGL. WebGL provides screen-space drawing plus fast 4×4 matrix operations to build your transformations in the shaders **you** write, which can be derived from Euler angles, quaternions, pure rotation matrices, or anything else you care to invent.

If you have better mathematics to manage rotations, then I encourage you to go ahead and write vertex shaders to compute it; no extensions to WebGL are required.